# Prepopulate Google Maps autocomplete (iOS / Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-autocomplete

Is it technically possible to make [Google Maps Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/autocomplete) search suggestions when it's just opened using coordinates or a hard-coded search string? Typically it shows empty field and a view below – layout is empty excepting `powered by Google` element:

[image]

Comment: You need to work with JSON and SearchDisplayController

Comment: Not possible with Google's autocomplete API

Answer (score -1):

Use the below url to send the request suggestion, you will get json response with the list of suggestions.Use that to display the suggestion in a tableview.I used this approach to in replacement or substitute of auto completion provided by google.
let url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=&types=geocode&key="

hope it helps you, 
Happy coding

Comment: I know it's difficult for the first time to understand the question but rather than giving the answer directly first do a comment if you have any question.